# Not able to send data over http to server using $.get() or $.post() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am just a beginner at jQuery or web coding.

I have created a jQuery slider which is programmed in a WiFi tiny server chip.
I am getting the slider graphics working, on client when connected to the tiny server with ip address `192.168.0.19`

However, the slider is not sending any data to the tiny server.

I have previously successfully sent data to tiny server with button click and `$.get()` function in jQuery.

But `$.get()` function is not working with the slider.

I must be missing something here which I can't figure out even by looking at other examples here. Please help me fixing the problem. Thanks.

Here is the slider code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>

<meta charset = "utf-8"> 
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-
ui.css" rel = "stylesheet"> 
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>     
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/custom.js"></script> 

<script>

$(function() {

$( "#slider" ).slider({

  orientation: "vertical",
  range: "max",
  value: 80,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,

  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#amount").html(ui.value);

  }
 });

 var value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
 $( "#amount" ).html( value );

 $.get("value");

});

</script>


</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jfunc.js"></script>

<div id="slider" style= "margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 200px; height:300px; 
width: 13px; background: #f22;"></div>

<div id="amount" style="color:#f22;font-size:75px; margin-left: 50px; 
margin-top: -250px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $.get("value"); is not sending any value and you do not handle the success/failure of the ajax call and it is only called then the page is loaded....

Comment: What can you see as output of this?

$.get( "value", function() {
  alert( "success" );
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });

Comment: $.get( "value", function() { alert( "success" ); }).fail(function() { alert( "error" ); });

I don't need to care for the "error" ...... I need to just send data "value" as it is over http to the tiny server.  and also I don't want any response back as "success". I will try adding this statement and see how it goes.

Can I truncate this statement and use only like this ;
$.get( "value", function() { alert( "success" ); }  );

Comment: @NafiulIslam
I tried using this statement. It didn't work. After logging into tiny server I only got a "success" response from the server. 
.
I think there should be some sort of mousemove or change event capture mechanism in place which will pass data to $.get() function. ??

Comment: Guys ..... nothing is working out at my end. Have tried different ways though.
Appreciate if you can edit my code to get the slider working and sending data to the server as the slider moves.